# Shrinking a physical transaction log file on a mirrored database

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, mirroring

I have 2 SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition instances that are mirrored.  Both instances are running Service Pack 1.

I run Full backups daily and transaction log backups every half hour (through maintenance plans).

My physical DB file is ~22GB. My physical log file has grown to ~41GB.

The log seems to grow the most when running a weekly `INDEX_REORGANIZE`. Last week it grew by 15GB. The previous week by 10GB.

My full backups are now ~50GB in size. Shouldn't that be around ~22GB? I feel that the transaction log backups are not properly clearing out space from the log file.

What is the safest way to shrink the transaction log file? I was looking at running `dbcc shrinkfile` after a transaction log backup.

Comment: BTW: the script I use to reorg the DB is here: https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html

Comment: [How to shrink the SQL Server log](http://rusanu.com/2012/07/27/how-to-shrink-the-sql-server-log/)

Comment: If your log is growing that much consistently, you'll want to leave it, otherwise all you're doing is saving space until the next growth event. At that point, SQL will just grow the log (again) and you'll have increased wait times while SQL grows the file (this adds time to your process). 

As for your backup file - are you appending to the existing file or are you creating a new file every time?

Comment: I create a new file every time.

Comment: I seconds @8bit in not shrinking t-log. Schedule your full db backup to run after a tlog backup after the reorg. This way all transactions will be backed up in the t-log backup and thus not included in the full, which should now result in 22GB. Also, try compressing your backups which should give you a much smaller backup size.

Comment: Bob - What do mean "compressing" them? Like Zipping them?

Comment: SQL 2008 has 'backup compression' as a server option in enterprise (standard in future releases), or using the WITH COMPRESSION option in your BACKUP DATABASE script.

Comment: You can use WITH COMPRESSION in Standard as well in 2008 R2 and up, so that might be enough motivation to get onto something more modern than SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Another thing to consider is that your index is growing - hence why your reorg is causing the log to bloat week by week. I'm not sure what your data growth looks like, so that's just speculation. 
Something to consider if your full backups are taking up 50GB nightly is to switch to a weekly full and daily differentials. 
Also, how often are you performing index maintenance?

Comment: I found out my mirror was paused due to an error 15 days ago! I resume mirroring, and after 6 or so hours, we are back in sync! However, now "log_reuse_wait_desc" shows "LOG_BACKUP" even though I ran an immediate T-Log backup.